# Bulk Upsert: How do I know which records have been created/updated?

Tags: bulk-api, upsert

I read that records are in the same order as they are sent, but what happens if I upsert 5 records and only 3 are fine? For example:

1. Fine
2. Fails
3. Fine
4. Fine
5. Fails

Am I going to receive 5 records or 3? If 3, I need to perform another query, sigh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/Content/asynch_api_batches_failed_records.htm) has a good description of how to handle failures.

You get back all records and any error messages:

```
"Id","Success","Created","Error"
"003D000000Q89kQIAR","true","true",""
"003D000000Q89kRIAR","true","true",""
"","false","false","REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING:Required fields are missing: [LastName]:LastName --"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I thought only successful records will be returned with with a "multiple records" request (a bulk upsert with more than one record)